# How do I change a commit message after a 'git-pull' auto-merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote, git-reset

Occasionally, my collaborators will "panic" when there is an automatic merge generated as the result a `git-pull`, and just accept the default commit message. Before this commit gets pushed, I want to be sure the message gets fixed, but `--amend` seems not to work. What is the best way to fix the message that's generated in this scenario. The best instructions I can come up with for them are

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
git merge -m <message> <the tracked remote branch>
```

but that seems a bit scary (`reset`) and error prone (the remote tracked branch has to be entered explicitly).

Is there a simple way to change the commit message that was just generated by merging with a remote tracking repo? Why doesn't `--amend` work?

Comment: `git commit --amend` works for me in this scenario (git 1.7.9.5). What trouble are you having with it? FYI, you can use `@{u}` to refer to the tracked remote branch.

Comment: @cbuckley: You're right! I [can't make this happen again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14576413/656912) (git 1.8.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git commit --amend` should work in this scenario. What exactly does not work?

Comment: perfect – forgot to mention in my answer: `git commit --amend` is also the absolutely correct tool for a situation like this.

Answer (score -1):

You can always try using git pull --rebase in order to put your commits on top of the tree.  But git warns against this saying.

"This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history already. Do not use this option unless you have read git-rebase(1) carefully." (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

If you are fine with eliminating the history of the merge then this is the option for you.

Answer (score -1):

`@{u}` is a good replacement for your `<the tracked remote branch>`, and then you can just glue the two steps into one. Perhaps a shell script you can distribute to them, or an alias they can add to their shells.

Comment: So is the `git reset --soft HEAD~` the "right" thing to do? Are there alternatives?