# Git: Commit message to merge master into branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge

While merging master into the current branch before a push if its not a fast-forward merge, git sets a default message `Merge branch 'master' into YOUR-BRANCH-NAME`.

But to make the git history more meaningful, what would be a standard message format for merge commits? Using the default message doesn't make much sense because the branch names would be random all the time(Branching strategy: GitHub flow).

Comment: If you are directly pushing `YOUR-BRANCH-NAME` to `master` without creating a PR, I think it's better to do `git pull origin -r master` instead of `git pull origin master` before push. With `-r` or `--rebase`, no merge commit is created.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unclear and asks about a too broad strategy for naming the commits, while not providing any desired goal and not clarifying what's wrong with the current behavior.

Comment: @ElpieKay I create merge requests(PR).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a [dedicated function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937574/6309) in order to get a custom merge message each time you merge one branch to another.
But after a `git pull`, only [`git commit --amend -m "new message"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14576413/6309) would change said message. You *might* be able to automate it in a [post-merge hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185449/6309).

But again, if you can avoid a pull-merge, and use a pull-rebase instead (for commits not yet pushed), that can be better: see [`git config pull.rebase true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309) in order to be able to use `git pull` as you do today, but with a rebase instead of a merge.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and supporting links, [git config pull.rebase true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309) would help me.